# HTTP status 404 the requested resource is not available while opening HTML page

Tags: javascript, java, html, eclipse, tomcat

I am a complete newbie to this and I'm using Eclipse Oxygen platform to run my application and Apache Tomcat 8.0.36 server.

Firstly, I created a simple HTML page first.html in WEB-INF folder inside my project.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>First Page</h1>
<a href="MiniPro/WebContent/WEB-INF/NewFile.html" >Press Here</a>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run this code, it directs to this link `http://localhost:8081/MiniPro/WEB-INF/first.html`
and shows an HTTP status 404 error.
Even when I tried this
`http://localhost:8081/MiniPro/WebContent/WEB-INF/first.html`
it shows the same error.

When I changed the location of first.html page into WebContent folder and run it is showing the result.

Can someone tell why it was not working when it is placed inside WEB-INF folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A special directory exists within the application hierarchy named 
>   WEB-INF. This directory contains all things related to the application
>   that aren’t in the document root of the application. The  WEB-INF node
>   is not part of the public document tree of the application. **No file
>   contained in the WEB-INF directory may be served directly to a client
>   by the container**. However, the contents of the  WEB-INF directory are
>   visible to servlet code using the getResource and `getResourceAsStream`
>   method calls on the `ServletContext`, and may be exposed using the
>   `RequestDispatcher` calls.

If you want to keep your file in WEB-INF - you need a Servlet to manage it.

Just a general example of how to get HTML file with servlet:

```
RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("mypage.html");
view.forward(request, response);
```

Otherwise, move your file outside WEB-INF and try to get it with `http://localhost:8081/MiniPro/first.html`

Answer (score 1):

You May try the `~/<path here >/<file>`

> **~** this will help you point the Home path from you **localhost**

You are using the path  like

**`MiniPro/WebContent/WEB-INF/NewFile.html`**
above that path has been located like

```
http://localhost:8081/MiniPro/WebContent/WEB-INF/first.html
```

so you can use instead of  **`http://localhost:8081`** use the **~**

```
~/MiniPro/WebContent/WEB-INF/NewFile.html
```

Answer (score 1):

the WEB-INF directory is special in a web project. It is designed that not allow direct visit for outside, but you can visit it with your servlet or jsp code.